# Total derivative of a function $f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by 
$$ f(x,y,z) = (x^z,y\tan(x^2z),\frac{1}{x+y})$$
and let $c: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by
$$c(t) = (\cos(t), \sin^2(\pi t), t+1)$$

a. Compute the total derivative $Df$ of $f$.

The first one I really dont know what is it mean?  which variable is it with respect to?

b. Write a formula for the path $f \circ c : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $

I think I would be ok when the first 2 questions are solved and I'll finished the other sub-questions. thank you dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to do your homework for you. (a) is straight forward, consider [Wiki article on Total Derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). You could've looked this up as well...

For (b) recall that $f \circ g(x) = f(g(x))$ so in your case
$$
f \circ c(t) = f(c(t)) = f(\cos(t), \sin^2(\pi t), t+1)
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'm not pretty sure because I haven't learn the total derivative, I just do it for some other reason, If I write it like that: $$Df = (zx^{z-1},\tan (x^2z),0) $$ like a differential operator, am I right?  Or just choose one of the variable like x,  and I do $$\frac{Df}{dx} = (zx^{z-1},2xyz\sec^2(x^2z),\frac{1}{x+y}$$like that?  thank you. p.s. I'm sorry I reply so late because I have some lectures after I posted this question.

Comment: @nanopotato Total derivative of $$f(x,y,z) = (xyz)^2$$ would be $$Df = 2x(yz)^2dx + 2y(xz)^2dy + 2z(xy)^2dx$$

Comment: Yes I know how to compute $Df$ when it's the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ from the wiki article but I'm still confused about the vector field($f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$). Sorry I'm noob in multivariables. Is it like a jacobian matrix form?

Comment: @nanopotato no :-) let $f = (x,y,z)$ then $$Df = (1,y,z)dx + (x,1,z)dy + (x,y,1)dz$$

Comment: thank you, it is clear now although it's quite bulky to compute, I still got the right ans.